# How to reference a large git repository as a submodule, without downloading the entire repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository for a program that embeds a Python interpreter, and in order to make it easier to keep it up-to-date with new versions of CPython, I'd like to add the [CPython github repository](https://github.com/python/cpython) as a submodule.

So far, so good, I can just do a `git submodule add https://github.com/python/cpython` and it'll work.

However, I notice that when I do that, git downloads a very large amount of data -- about 444MB, and it takes 10-20 minutes for this download to complete on my machine.

My question is, given that I'll only be using a subset of the github repository's data (i.e. only the current revision of a single branch), is there a way to configure my git submodule such that it doesn't have to download all 444MB each time I clone my parent repository and then do the `git submodule update --init --recursive` step?  It would be nice if I could cut down on the time and bandwidth needed.